# Get debug selection in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, listener, selection

I've got an Eclipse product from my plugins. In this product you can create a Java Source and debug it normally.

**My question is**: how can I retrieve the debug selection? Maybe I have to add a selection listener? Where?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain it more please?

Comment: Suppose I've got some eclipse plugins, then I launch an Eclipse application from one of theese. In new eclipse application I create a Java source and I debug it. I need to catch debug selection.

Comment: Now its more confusing :( Maybe other members can better understand your problem. GL.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `LaunchViewCopyToClipboardActionDelegate` from the `org.eclipse.debug.ui` plugin.

Comment: And how can I send a command (like IStepInto) to debug plugin?

Comment: A hack & slash way would be to find the action class for step into in the debug plugin that corresponds to the language you're debugging, create a new instance, and call run() on it.